# Adding ID's to google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a script that loops and adds markers one at a time.

I am trying to get the current marker to have an info window and and only have 5 markers on a map at a time (4 without info windows and 1 with)

How would I add an id to each marker so that I can delete and close info windows as needed.

This is the function I am using to set the marker:

```
function codeAddress(address, contentString) {

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

if (geocoder) {

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map, 
          position: results[0].geometry.location
       });

       infowindow.open(map,marker);

      } else {
       alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

}

Answer (score 206, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamic language.  You could just add it to the object itself.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.metadata = {type: "point", id: 1};
```

Also, because all v3 objects extend [`MVCObject()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCObject).  You can use:

```
marker.setValues({type: "point", id: 1});
// or
marker.set("type", "point");
marker.set("id", 1);
var val = marker.get("id");
```

Comment: I am curious how, once you have given markers id's, how you woud go about accessing these markers outside of the map canvas. $('#1').doSomething(); for example?

Comment: @willdanceforfun Add click event to the marker and get information on `this`: `google.maps.event.addListener(yourMarker, 'click', function (event) { console.log(this); });`

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for a solution to access the id outside of the map. You can keep track of your markers by pushing it to an array. This way, you can access the marker afterwards by iterating through the markers array

Answer (score 19):

Just adding another solution that works for me.. You can simply append it in the marker options:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map, 
    position: position,

    // Custom Attributes / Data / Key-Values
    store_id: id,
    store_address: address,
    store_type: type
});
```

And then retrieve them with:

```
marker.get('store_id');
marker.get('store_address');
marker.get('store_type');
```

Comment: This helped a bunch. None of the examples had this. Good for passing values for consumption with click return functions.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple `Location` class that I use to handle all of my marker-related things. I'll paste my code below for you to take a gander at.

The last line(s) is what actually creates the marker objects. It loops through some JSON of my locations, which look something like this:

```
{"locationID":"98","name":"Bergqvist Järn","note":null,"type":"retail","address":"Smidesvägen 3","zipcode":"69633","city":"Askersund","country":"Sverige","phone":"0583-120 35","fax":null,"email":null,"url":"www.bergqvist-jb.com","lat":"58.891079","lng":"14.917371","contact":null,"rating":"0","distance":"45.666885421019"}
```

Here is the code:

If you look at the `target()` method in my Location class, you'll see that I keep references to the infowindow's and can simply `open()` and `close()` them because of a reference.

See a live demo: http://ww1.arbesko.com/en/locator/ (type in a Swedish city, like stockholm, and hit enter)

```
var Location = function() {
    var self = this,
        args = arguments;

    self.init.apply(self, args);
};

Location.prototype = {
    init: function(location, map) {
        var self = this;

        for (f in location) { self[f] = location[f]; }

        self.map = map;
        self.id = self.locationID;

        var ratings = ['bronze', 'silver', 'gold'],
            random = Math.floor(3*Math.random());

        self.rating_class = 'blue';

        // this is the marker point
        self.point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(self.lat), parseFloat(self.lng));
        locator.bounds.extend(self.point);

        // Create the marker for placement on the map
        self.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: self.point,
            title: self.name,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/arbesko/img/locator/'+self.rating_class+'SmallMarker.png'),
            shadow: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                                        '/wp-content/themes/arbesko/img/locator/smallMarkerShadow.png',
                                        new google.maps.Size(52, 18),
                                        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                        new google.maps.Point(19, 14)
                                    )
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(self.marker, 'click', function() {
            self.target('map');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(self.marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            self.sidebarItem().mouseover();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(self.marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            self.sidebarItem().mouseout();
        });

        var infocontent = Array(
            '<div class="locationInfo">',
                '<span class="locName br">'+self.name+'</span>',
                '<span class="locAddress br">',
                    self.address+'<br/>'+self.zipcode+' '+self.city+' '+self.country,
                '</span>',
                '<span class="locContact br">'
        );

        if (self.phone) {
            infocontent.push('<span class="item br locPhone">'+self.phone+'</span>');
        }

        if (self.url) {
            infocontent.push('<span class="item br locURL"><a href="http://'+self.url+'">'+self.url+'</a></span>');
        }

        if (self.email) {
            infocontent.push('<span class="item br locEmail"><a href="mailto:'+self.email+'">Email</a></span>');
        }

        // Add in the lat/long
        infocontent.push('</span>');

        infocontent.push('<span class="item br locPosition"><strong>Lat:</strong> '+self.lat+'<br/><strong>Lng:</strong> '+self.lng+'</span>');

        // Create the infowindow for placement on the map, when a marker is clicked
        self.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infocontent.join(""),
            position: self.point,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -15) // Offset the infowindow by 15px to the top
        });

    },

    // Append the marker to the map
    addToMap: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.marker.setMap(self.map);
    },

    // Creates a sidebar module for the item, connected to the marker, etc..
    sidebarItem: function() {
        var self = this;

        if (self.sidebar) {
            return self.sidebar;
        }

        var li = $('<li/>').attr({ 'class': 'location', 'id': 'location-'+self.id }),
            name = $('<span/>').attr('class', 'locationName').html(self.name).appendTo(li),
            address = $('<span/>').attr('class', 'locationAddress').html(self.address+' <br/> '+self.zipcode+' '+self.city+' '+self.country).appendTo(li);

        li.addClass(self.rating_class);

        li.bind('click', function(event) {
            self.target();
        });

        self.sidebar = li;

        return li;
    },

    // This will "target" the store. Center the map and zoom on it, as well as 
    target: function(type) {
        var self = this;

        if (locator.targeted) {
            locator.targeted.infowindow.close();
        }

        locator.targeted = this;

        if (type != 'map') {
            self.map.panTo(self.point);
            self.map.setZoom(14);
        };

        // Open the infowinfow
        self.infowindow.open(self.map);
    }
};

for (var i=0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = new Location(locations[i], self.map);
    self.locations.push(location);

    // Add the sidebar item
    self.location_ul.append(location.sidebarItem());

    // Add the map!
    location.addToMap();
};
```

Comment: That does **not** answer the question. At all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an cache that stores each marker object and references an ID?

```
var markerCache= {};
var idGen= 0;

function codeAddress(addr, contentStr){
    // create marker
    // store
    markerCache[idGen++]= marker;
}
```

Edit: of course this relies on a numeric index system that doesn't offer a length property like an array. You could of course prototype the Object object and create a length, etc for just such a thing. OTOH, generating a unique ID value (MD5, etc) of each address might be the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Marker already has unique id

```
marker.__gm_id
```

Comment: The only solution I would use out of these.

Comment: The double underscore and `gm` prefix should indicate to you that this is a private variable that has not guarantees. Avoid it.