# Creating Google Maps Marker including id attribute

Tags: jquery, google-maps

sorry for maybe a stupid question but I've read [Adding ID's to google map markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564320/adding-ids-to-google-map-markers) before without success.

I try to create a map with a number of markers. I would like to use jquery to work with this markers. Simple $('#marker1').doSomething(); 
How is it possible to give this marker a valued id attribute? My really simple demo code will show you the way i tried to make it work.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Hello World!',
  });
  marker.set("type", "point");
  marker.set("id", "ABC");
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`var marker` holds the marker object. You can add your own properties to this object

```
marker.type = "point";

marker.myID = "ABC";
```

You will probably want to keep track of all the markers you create, create an array outside your function to give it scope. And push all markers you create to this array.

```
var markers = [];

function initialise()
{
    // Initialise the map etc.

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // Marker options
    });

    marker.type = "type";

    marker.myID = 4

    markers.push(marker);
}
```

If you create other markers, just push them to the array you've created. To access them just iterate over the array with `$.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind a click event to a marker using the following method:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    type: 'point'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // do something. You may use jQuery here.
});
```

You can add any amount of data to a marker such as:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    type: 'point',
    somedata: true
});
```

And then use that object to do certain actions on click, such as...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (this.somedata) doSomething();
});
```

Additionally if you're putting down multiple markers you can add click events to all of them  by using a simple loop.

A good example is that I have an array of lat/lng positions and want to drop markers for each of them and have each of them do something different on click. I can set a few arrays, one with lat/lng coordinates and the second with matching titles and, lets say, an html element that exists elsewhere on the page (so that on click it removes that element, as an example).

```
var markers  = [],
    marker_i = 0,
    marker_p = ['-25.363882,131.044922','-25.363882,133.044922'],
    marker_t = ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    marker_d = ['.foo', '.bar'];

for (var i = 0; i < marker_pos.length; i++) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker_p[i],
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        type: 'point',
        title: marker_t[i],
        htmlelement: marker_d[i]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[marker_i], 'click', function() {
        $(this.htmlelement).remove();
    });

    marker_i++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I want to do, is to make the marker draggable outside of the Map. So that you can drop a marker inside of a i.e. a <div> using jquery. The <div> is not related to the gmap. Thanks for your help! I am very sorry, but that isn't possible with your solutions.