# google maps can't add proper marker ID

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When my google map have finished loading grab all the saved destinations from the database through an ajax post in my view:

```
     success: function (data) {
            for (destination in data) {
                var latlng = { lat: data[destination].Latitude, lng: data[destination].Longitude }
                console.log(data[destination].Id);
                console.log(data[destination]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    postion: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),

                });
                marker.set("id", data[destination].Id);

                marker.setIcon( /** {google.maps.Icon} */({
                    url: '/Content/Markers/green_MarkerX.png',
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
                }));
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                marker.setVisible(true);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    console.log("MARKER");
                    console.log(marker);
                    console.log("MarkerID");
                    console.log(marker.get('id'));
                });
            }
        },
```

I in the first console.log i write out the id of the destination and that works fine. The id of every destination writes out as it should. Later in the function i add the id to the marker so that i will be able to find the marker when i click on it. 
But when i click on any of my markers they all get the id of 12 since there is 12 destinations in my database. whats wrong?

Comment: please follow this link , i hope you will get your answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463804/creating-google-maps-marker-including-id-attribute

Comment: @SumitJha they all still get the same id of 12

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 'destination.Latitude' in place of 'data[destination].Latitude'. Because "for x in y" iterates through each element of y and sets it to x. You are treating it as index.

Comment: yeah that is kind of weird. But somehow destination is an index of the dataobject it iterates through and not the object. So if im using it like destination.Latitude it will be undefined

Comment: it has to do with something about the marker id and how it is set though because the console.log writes the correct id but all the markers gets the id of 12

Answer (score 0):

just little change in you code :
  access your marker id in your click as data[destination].Id. an see code

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                  console.log("MarkerID");
                 console.log(data[destination].Id);
                });
```